# Icons in overflow menu

Tags: android, menu, icons

I have an overflow menu with 3 items in it.  I have an icon for one of the items by creating a method and then calling that method.  The only thing is that it gives me one icon.  How can I put more than one icon next to the items in my overflow menu?  Here is my code for the method of the one I have (which is a settings icon:

```
private void setIconInMenu(Menu menu, int menuItemID, int labelId, int iconID) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(menuItemID);
    SpannableStringBuilder builder =
            new SpannableStringBuilder("          " + getResources().getString(labelId));
    builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(this, iconID), 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    item.setTitle(builder);
```

This is the code that calls the method:

```
setIconInMenu(menu, R.id.action_preferences, R.string.menu_action_preferences,
            R.drawable.ic_settings_white_24dp);
```

So I want to some icons for other items in the menu.

Thanks.
Robert

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just using an array list with a custom adapter that takes in a drawable parameter?

Comment: I will try this!  Thanks.